# Concerning Gauss Sums

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Given a character $\chi$ modulo $q$, define the Gauss sum
>
> $$\tau(\chi) := \sum_{a=1}^q\chi(a)e\bigg(\frac{a}{q}\bigg) $$
>
> where $e(x) := e^{2\pi ix}$. Show that
>
> $$\frac{1}{\varphi} \cdot \sum_{\chi} \overline{\chi}(a)\tau(\chi) = \begin{cases}&e\bigg(\frac{a}{q}\bigg) &\text{ if } gcd(a,q)=1\\&0 &else \end{cases}$$

The case $gcd(a,q) \ne 1$ is clear, so let us assume $gcd(a,q) = 1$. If I am not mistaken we then have:

$$\sum_{\chi} \overline{\chi}(a)\tau(\chi) = \sum_{\chi} \sum_{a=1}^q \overline{\chi}(a) \cdot \chi(a) \cdot e\bigg(\frac{a}{q}\bigg)=  \sum_{\chi} \sum_{a=1}^q e\bigg(\frac{a}{q}\bigg)$$

So I do not see how I should continue from here. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the variable $a$ in two different ways
(both as a free variable and as a bound one). I would write
$$\sum_\chi\overline\chi(a)\tau(\chi)=\sum_\chi\overline\chi(a)\sum_{b=1}^q
\chi(b)e(b/q)$$
and then reverse the order of summation.